# Power BI Gateway with different account

Tags: powerbi

I uninstalled my Power BI Enterprise gateway because I want to install a new gateway to work with a demo Office365 E5 account.

But when I reinstall the gateway, the installation wizard forwards me automatically to my work account instead.

Does anyone know how I can choose the account for which I want to configure the gateway?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi when you are installing you will get a [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install#download-and-install-a-standard-gateway) (See point 4) to choose New gateway or migrate,restore takeover option. Choose New gateway option and enter email.